Python zeep xsi:type="xsd:string"
I'm trying to make a correct document, but it's not working. I need to wrap "value" in xsi:type="xsd:string"tag
plz tell me how to do this)
Thank you
...
from zeep import Client, Transport

...
# it's work

    def add_temp_person_identifier(self,
                                   person_session_id=None,
                                   person_id=None,
                                   access_group_id=None):
        if person_session_id is None:
            person_session_id = self.open_person_editing_session(person_id=person_id)['value']

        namespace = ''

        for key, value in self.client.namespaces.items():
            if value == "http://localsite.com/IntergationService":
                namespace = key
        IdentifierType = self.client.get_type(f"{namespace}:IdentifierTemp")

        Identifier = IdentifierType(CODE='0000',
                                    IS_PRIMARY=False,
                                    PERSON_ID=person_id,)
        result = self.client.service.AddPersonIdentifier(person_session_id, Identifier)
        self.close_person_editing_session(person_session_id)
        return result


# need help with it. "value" must be in xsi:type="xsd:string" tag

    def find_by_login(self, login):
        return self.client.service.PersonSearch(self.session_id,
                                                fieldID='0de358e0',
                                                relation=0,
                                                value=login)


I googled + read the instructions but I don’t have the slightest idea how to follow it correctly.

context:
I needed to generate request like this:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<PersonSearch xmlns="http://localsite/yyyyyy">
.....
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxxx</value>
</PersonSearch>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`


As can be seen from the example, the API expects the contents of the tag to be specified explicitly. For this you must have a parameter specified, such as a field.
xsd.AnyObject(xsd.String(), login) - assigns a "string" data type parameter, taking it from a generic library object.
from zeep import Client, Transport, xsd

def find_by_login(self, login):
    return self.client.service.PersonSearch(self.session_id,
                                            fieldID='43a278d1',
                                            relation=0,
                                            value=xsd.AnyObject(xsd.String(), login))


While it is great that you found an answer to your question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks
